# I am unable to fetch the data in my application from my Website(dashboard in PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, server, localhost

I have developed an project for News application and I have both Dashboard and Android Application ready!
Now, I have to host my server side code (Dashboard) on hosting website. I chose 000webhost for testing purposes and hosted on that. I am able to fetch the data in app and able to post from dashboard when hosted on 000webhost, but when I have chose another services like BlueHost, InfinityFree then I am unable to fetch the data in my application!

Now the problem is-
Since I have developed my application using local servers so my **config.php** look likes this

```
<?php

//database configuration
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "epiz_24504438";
$pass       = "******";
$database   = "epiz_24504438_myapp_db";

$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if (!$connect) {
    die ("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    $connect->set_charset('utf8');
}

$GLOBALS['config'] = $connect;


$ENABLE_RTL_MODE = 'false';

?>
```

But when I have to upload it on hosting services websites the have a forced SQL **host**-name like

```
<?php

//database configuration
$host       = "sql211.epizy.com";
$user       = "epiz_24504438";
$pass       = "******";
$database   = "epiz_24504438_myapp_db";

$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

if (!$connect) {
    die ("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} else {
    $connect->set_charset('utf8');
}

$GLOBALS['config'] = $connect;


$ENABLE_RTL_MODE = 'false';

?>
```

Due to **sql211.epizy.com** I am able to access my Dashboard(no data in application) and when I am changing it to localhost then I am not able to access both dashboard and data in application.

While on 000webhost they have SQL host as locahost so it working fine there on both application and dashboard but due to limitations of free hosting I don't want to use it!

So please help me out!! What should I do?

Comment: Normally, each environment has its own configuration. I don't get where your  problem is.

Comment: Are globals enabled on both servers?

Comment: Take a look at the dotenv package

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = new PDO(('mysql:host= ;dbname= ', ' ', ' ');
```

Example:

```
$connect = new PDO(('mysql:host= hosturl;dbname= ', 'user', 'password');
```